# Xamarin Forms - TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a Grid programmatically, and i want to add a Tap Gesture Recognizer to each layout, and passing some parameters with it. I'm using MVVM pattern.

Here is how i'm doing this :

```
    public SelectProfileViewModel()
    {
        _userGrid = new Grid();

        _userGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        _userGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        _userGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = 150 });
        _userGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = 150 });
        _userGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = 150 });

        _userGrid.Children.Add(createUserView("A"), 0, 0);
        _userGrid.Children.Add(createUserView("B"), 1, 0);
        _userGrid.Children.Add(createUserView("C"), 0, 1);
        _userGrid.Children.Add(createUserView("D"), 1, 1);
        _userGrid.Children.Add(createUserView("E"), 2, 0);
    }

    private View createUserView(string name)
    {
        var parentView = new StackLayout { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
            parentView.Children.Add(new Image { Source = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ1Gevu4Tk803Ydc4VywH_ANoJSf3B6rnuI64IChMJSdw9qfR7s", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center } );
        parentView.Children.Add(new Label { Text = name, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center } );

        var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapGestureRecognizer.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty, "SelectProfileCommand");
        tapGestureRecognizer.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty, name);
        parentView.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);

        return parentView;
    }
```

When i click on the child view, the command is well called. But the parameter is null.

Here is the command and parameter part :

```
public ICommand SelectProfileCommand => new Command<string>(async (name) => await SelectProfileAsync(name));

private async Task SelectProfileAsync(string name)
{
    await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<LoginViewModel>(name);
}
```

Anyone has an idea of what's happening ?

Thanks.

Comment: where is `name` defined?

Comment: name is the parameter sent : "createUserView(name)" and added to the command as parameter

Comment: you are using `name` to create the `CommandParameter` binding - you have to specify the name of the property that you want to fill that binding for you.  You are getting a null because it can't find a property `name` to complete the binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binding refers to a property. So you are trying to bind to properties called `A, B, C, ...`. If this should work, you have to have properties with these names in your binding context.

If you just want to set the parameter to a constant value you can do it by changing

```cs
tapGestureRecognizer.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty, name);
// to
tapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameter = name;
```